# The 3-level hierarchy of keys in TPM 2.0

Tags: key-management, tpm

I have a task to create the 3-level RSA key hierarchy (*with wolfTPM library*), where keys of the 2nd and the 3rd levels are imported keys.
Here are the steps that I follow:

1. Generate a primary key on the TMP.
2. Generate a secondary key externally and import it to the TPM and be protected by the primary key.
3. Generate external keys (*the 3rd level*) and encrypt them with the secondary key.

I was able to do the 1st and 2nd steps.
When I try to import external keys (*3rd level*) under the 2nd level of keys, I get an error TPM_RC_VALUE.